# How to call sslSocket.setHostname()?

Tags: java, android, ssl, sni

My goals:

1. SSLv3 explicitly disabled - implies overriding the list of enabled protocols on the factory class
2. SNI enabled - **implies calling setHostname on socket before handshake**

pseudo-code

```
SSLCertificateSocketFactory factory = SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getDefault(timeout);
// set keystore and truststore, etc.
httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(factory);
```

In other words, I don't even see the socket.

Given the SSLCertificateSocketFactory does not have any public constructor and the setters on HttpsURLConnection expect a factory class (rather than an interface) I don't see how I can intercept between the factory and the connection so I can call the setHostname...

Comment: You could write a subclass of `SSLCertificateSocketFactory` that provides the constructor you need.

Comment: @Michael Unfortunately SSLCertificateSocketFactory has no non-private constructors.

Comment: You can pass an `SSLCertificateSocketFactory` instance as a parameter to your derived class' constructor.

Comment: @Michael Your new constructor will have no way of calling any super-constructor, hence it will not compile. :(

Comment: Ah, right. Although `SSLCertificateSocketFactory(int handshakeTimeoutMillis)` is still public, it's just marked as deprecated. Another alternative could be to take the source for `SSLCertificateSocketFactory` and implement your own version based off of it.

Comment: @Michael yes, i am afraid i will have to go with the "copy-paste" approach :(